# Awk file separation using delimiters

Tags: linux, shell, awk

Given this input file:

```
SectionMarker and some random text here
this is the text in section 1 
this is the text in section 1
this is the text in section 1
etc
SectionMarker and some random text here also
this is the text in section 2 
this is the text in section 2
this is the text in section 2
etc
SectionMarker and some random text too
this is the text in section 3 
this is the text in section 3
this is the text in section 3
etc
```

How do I split this file in pieces using awk or sed or whatever ?

This is what I tried, but didn't work:

```
awk -vRS='\SectionMarker[:print:]\n' 'NR==1 {print}' ./data.log
```

Comment: What output you're expecting?

Comment: The output i am expecting in my example is the text in the first section: "this is the text in section 1 
this is the text in section 1
this is the text in section 1
etc"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this one-liner should do the job:

```
 awk '{x+=($0~/^SectionMarker/)?1:0}x<2' data.log
```

test

```
kent$  cat data.log
SectionMarker and some random text here
this is the text in section 1 
this is the text in section 1
this is the text in section 1
etc
SectionMarker and some random text here also
this is the text in section 2 
this is the text in section 2
this is the text in section 2
etc
SectionMarker and some random text too
this is the text in section 3 
this is the text in section 3
this is the text in section 3
etc

kent$  awk '{x+=($0~/^SectionMarker/)?1:0}x<2' data.log
SectionMarker and some random text here
this is the text in section 1 
this is the text in section 1
this is the text in section 1
etc
```

i don't know how many sections in your real problem you want to grab. you could place `exit;` in that onliner to make awk not process the whole file.

Comment: Thank you that works. How can i edit the command to get only the 2th section (or 3th) ?

Comment: @Daps0l just change x<2 to x==2 (2nd section) or x==3 to  get 3rd section.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using `awk` and the read separator. I have added an extra variable called `var`, and this could be used to select the desired 'section' with ease. For example, when `var=2`, section 2 will be printed. i.e:

```
awk -v var=2 -v RS='SectionMarker[^\n]*' -v FS='\n' 'NR == var + 1 { for (i=2; i<NF; i++) print $i }' file.txt
```

prints:

```
this is the text in section 2 
this is the text in section 2
this is the text in section 2
etc
```

HTH